# How do i deal with getRange() Class error in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working in Google Script and trying to get values from following column. Any idea of why i am getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined", and how to deal with it?
Here is following code:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
const workspaceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Workspaces")
function getWorkspaces (workspaceSheet) {
  WORKSPACE_ID = workspaceSheet.getRange(1,1,100).getValues()
  return WORKSPACE_ID
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `getWorkspaces` is run as the custom function, an error occurs at `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);`. From this situation, I thought that you might have directly run the function of `getWorkspaces` with the script editor. If my understanding is correct, when `getWorkspaces` is run with the script editor, `workspaceSheet` of `getWorkspaces(workspaceSheet)` is `undefined`. By this, such error occurs. If you want to remove your issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, `workspaceSheet` of `getWorkspaces(workspaceSheet)` is removed. By this, `workspaceSheet` of `const workspaceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Workspaces");` is used.

```
const ssId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
const workspaceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Workspaces");

function getWorkspaces() {
  WORKSPACE_ID = workspaceSheet.getRange(1, 1, 100).getValues();
  return WORKSPACE_ID;
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, `ss` and `workspaceSheet` are declared in the function.

```
function getWorkspaces() {
  const ssId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  const workspaceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Workspaces");
  WORKSPACE_ID = workspaceSheet.getRange(1, 1, 100).getValues();
  return WORKSPACE_ID;
}
```

#### Modified script 3:

When you want to call `getWorkspaces` from other function, how about the following modified script?

```
function getWorkspaces(workspaceSheet) {
  WORKSPACE_ID = workspaceSheet.getRange(1, 1, 100).getValues();
  return WORKSPACE_ID;
}

// In this case, please run this function. By this, `getWorkspaces` is run.
function sample() {
  const ssId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  const workspaceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Workspaces");
  const WORKSPACE_ID = getWorkspaces(workspaceSheet);
  console.log(WORKSPACE_ID);
}
```

Comment: I used first modification and it worked, the only thing that was needed to do was delete workspaceSheet from function parameters. Thank you!